# undelete missing for a posting recently deleted

Tags: support, user-interface, deleted-questions

I have just deleted " Towards generalization of Euler relation ". I wish to fix it and re-post it , but it is missing from " ask questions " or other headings. How to recover the same?   TIA

Answer (score 9):

At the bottom of the [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/95860/narasimham?tab=questions) tab of your profile, there's a [deleted recent questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/95860) link. Deleted questions that you asked in the last 60 days are listed there. (There's a similar link for deleted recent answers at the bottom of the "answers" tab of course.)

For momentary convenience: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1164665/towards-functional-generalization-of-eulers-identity)'s the link to the question.